# Button click not firing in Internet 7 and 8 compatibility mode

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, buttonclick

I have an ASP.NET button control which is working fine in IE 9 but it's click event is not being fired in IE 7 and IE 8. I checked into my program and found that there is no button control Id  in Request.Form.AllKeys collection in case when I am using IE 7 and IE 8.

Any help will be highly appreciated !!!

Comment: Do you get any javascript error?

Comment: No.while debugging it successfully passes through the page load event handler but never goes to button click event handler there onwards...